# Can we set file permissions based on file system groups or ACL for cloud native applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, azure-storage, azure-aks

Does the usage of filesystem access control lists is a good practice for cloud-native application design? Does native K8s storage types support it?

I would like to assign file permissions based on Linux file system groups. I want only specific users to have RWX access and others to be limited to Read. Does commonly used storage types support it or some don’t.

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Using file-based permissions goes against "no state" based designs. Most serverless services do not support file systems access except for a TMP volume which is usually in memory/transient. There really is no concept of users except what you create thru your own design. Kubernetes does allow user-based permissions for persistent volumes, but that is not portable to other services. Anything "user-based" should be at a layer above the application - OAuth + Database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, permissions for specific users (`UID`) and groups (`GID`) can be set for volumes mounted in containers using three ways:

1. [Security Context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) - using security context, we can specify

   - User ID (`UID`) for `runAsUser`
   - Group ID (`GID`) for `runAsGroup` and `fsGroup`

   ```
   ...
   kind: Pod
   ...
   spec:
     securityContext:
       runAsUser: 1000
       runAsGroup: 3000
       fsGroup: 2000
     volumes:
     ...
     containers:
     ...
   ```
2. Use `chown` and/or `chmod` in [Init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

   ```
   ...
   kind: Pod
   ...
   spec:
     initContainers:
     - name: set-data-dir-permission
       image: my_image
       command:
       - chown
       - -R
       - myuser:mygroup
       - /my_directory
       volumeMounts:
       - name: data
         mountPath: /my_directory
     containers:
     ...
   ```
3. Using the `readOnly`, `mode` and `accessModes` fields for [persistent volumes.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)

Kubernetes also supports assigning [SELinux labels to a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#assign-selinux-labels-to-a-container) using the `seLinuxOptions` field in the `securityContext` section of the Pod manifest. The `seLinuxOptions` field is an [`SELinuxOptions`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#selinuxoptions-v1-core) object.

Comment: In Linux, we have commands like setfacl and getfacl through which we can set different permissions based on groups and users. My plan is to create a microservice which generates files and share access based on groups. I would like to store these files in a persistent storage location which means I will use a PVC object in Kubernetes.  I would like to understand if storage types like NFS, CEPH, glusterFS etc. support this functionality. In case if a specific storageClass or types doesn't support it, it would be good to list them out.

Comment: Wasn't able to find much about ACL'ing PVs except this GitHub thread (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47326#issuecomment-307694312). You should be able to use the Linux ACL commands `setfacl` and `getfacl` in the init container approach. Wonder if group-based access modes can be created using `accessModes` for PVCs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims).